# Widget not available on all devices

Tags: android, android-widget

I've developed an Android app with a widget. The application and widget worked fine for many versions but since the latest version I got many complaints from users that the widget is disappeared on some devices. I do not see any correlation between the devices and the problems. More over, I did not change anything about the widget. I double checked with a previous version and nothing has changed about that.
The only thing that changed is the Android SDK and the Eclipse version. Although I build for the same API level, I suspect something has changed.

I've two different Android devices (2.3.6 & 4.1) and on both the widget works fine.
I have no clue.

Anyone?

Comment: The problem might be the place where the application is installed, as Installing application on SDCARD or moving it to SDCARD, make the widget disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause was found: for some reason the copy-protection field was set to OFF in the Play Store publish section. Because an option `android:installLocation="preferExternal` was set in the AndroidManifest file, the application now suddenly installed itself on SD. Before this was prevented by the copy-protection. 
Both my devices haven't an SD card installed so that explains why I didn't see the problem.

Comment: did you used `auto` or `internalOnly` to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Find out which devices.  Try to find a user with the widget problem that's willing to work with you on the problem.  You could send them a custom build with extra debug outputs, memory statistics, versions, etc.  Or try and get your hands on a device just like theirs.

Comment: But even then, how can we debug this? You need to add a section to the manifest file and then the widget is picked up by Android when showing the list of available widgets. If that doesn't happen, where and how should we start debugging?

Comment: If that doesn't happen, there may be a problem with your AppWidgetProvider class implementation, or your AppWidgetProviderInfo object, and that problem only occurs on certain devices.